# How to update a table to the values in a sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am need to carry out some remedial work against my database in order to correct some data errors.  I have a numeric field in the target table which I need to update to the results of an underlying query.  There are approximately 30,000 rows to update.

Have tried a number of permutations of the code detailed below without success.  I realise the code supplied is incorrect but I am hoping that you guys will be able to deduce from it, what I am trying to achieve.

```
UPDATE TARGETTABLE
SET NUMFIELD = IL1.NUMFIELD 
(
SELECT IL1.ID, IL1.NUMFIELD FROM 
  (
    SELECT H.ID, TRUNC(TO_CHAR(H.TIMEFIELD,'FF9')/1000000,'000')
    "NUMFIELD" FROM HISTORIC_ALARM_LOG@REMOTETABLE
    WHERE ID IN
    (
      SELECT ID FROM TARGETTABLE 
      WHERE (NUMFIELD = 0 OR NUMFIELD = 1)
      AND TIMEFIELD BETWEEN TO_DATE('23 Apr 2019 00:00:00','DD MON YYYY 
      HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('25 Apr 2019 00:00:00','DD MON YYYY
      HH24:MI:SS') 
      AND DATASOURCEID = 3
    )
  ) IL1
)
```

Comment: its unfortunately difficult to understand what you want with that query only

Comment: Thomas thanks for your swift feedback.  The target table has a number of records which correspond to records in the remote table.  I need to update the time field in the target table will the correct numeric value from the time field in the remote table

Comment: You need a `Where` clause for the `Update` statement. `Where Targettable.ID = IL1.ID` Unless I'm misunderstanding this question, which is entirely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the logic that you want:

```
UPDATE TARGETTABLE tt
    SET NUMFIELD = (SELECT "NUMFIELD"
                    FROM HISTORIC_ALARM_LOG@REMOTETABLE rt
                    WHERE rt.ID = tt.id
                   )
WHERE tt.NUMFIELD IN (0, 1) AND
      tt.TIMEFIELD >= DATE '2019-04-23' AND
      tt.TIMEFIELD >= DATE '2019-04-25' AND
      tt.DATASOURCEID = 3;
```

Notes:

- The filtering on the rows to update should be in the outermost `WHERE` (associated with the `UPDATE`).
- You need a correlation clause.
- Use `DATE` constants -- they are safer and simpler to write.